# Does Blender API have any evaluation function for Bezier curves?

Tags: python, export, bezier-curves

I'm trying to export Blender Bezier Paths to Unity, so that Unity objects can follow along those paths.

The 2 ways to do this that I came up with so far are:

1. Blender script creates an empty for every control point in the Blender path, then those get imported into Unity as empty game objects (aka transforms) and from within Unity I can calculate B(t) based on the control points.
2. Blender script takes a "resolution" parameter, which it uses to
   evaluate the path and instead create an empty along the path for
   each sample. Then those get imported into Unity as empties and from
   within Unity I just have the objects follow this checkpoints along
   the path.

For approach 2, I'd need to evaluate the spline inside blender. And I was hoping that bpy.types.Curve would have an eval(t) or similar method but I haven't found anything in the API so far.

So my question is, is there anything in the Blender API for evaluating or do I need to write the evaluation code myself?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found it: [`mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier).